# Proving that multiply by exponent in time domain yields a frequency shift in frequency domain using convolution.

Tags: fourier-analysis, convolution

I'm trying to prove that $F[x(t)e^{-jat}] = X(w-a)$ using convolution.
using the convolution property I know I should get a convolution of $F(x(t))$ and $F(e^{-jat})$ 
So:

$$
F[x(t)e^{-jat}]= 1/2\pi X(w)*2\pi\delta(w+a) = \int X(\theta)\delta(\omega+a-\theta) d\theta
$$
as we know the delta function samples at the impulse moment therefore I get:
$$
X(\omega+a)
$$
and not $X(\omega-a)$
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You just have the Fourier transform of $\exp$ wrong.

Comment: You probably have the sign of the exponent wrong.